# CGRect changes width when device rotated

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgcontext, cgrect

I want to draw a XoY coordinate axis... The axis are CGRects .. the thing is they change width when the device is rotated ... I would want them to maintain their with in all rotations. Does width 5.0 mean different things when the device is in portrait rather than landscape?

Here is the code:

```
   CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);

    // the axis is a rect ...
    //axis start point
    CGFloat axisStartX = viewBounds.size.width * LEFT_EXCLUSION_LENGTH_PERCENT;
    CGFloat axisStartY = viewBounds.size.height * UNDER_EXCLUSION_LENGTH_PERCENT;

    CGFloat axisLength = viewBounds .size.height - (viewBounds.size.height * OVER_EXCLUSION_LENGTH_PERCENT) - viewBounds.size.height * UNDER_EXCLUSION_LENGTH_PERCENT;
    CGContextAddRect(ctx, CGRectMake(axisStartX, axisStartY, AXIS_LINE_WIDTH, axisLength));



    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

Comment: The device **Width** and **height** have different values in portrait and landscape mode and as you are using viewBounds.size its going to be different.

Answer (score 2):

I would not know what you are up to with this calculation, but viewBounds.size.height may change on rotation, depending on what it represents. But if its height varies for different orientations then the axisLength will vary too. And axisLength is the height of your rect.

Comment: Fine. But what ist self? Meaning, what are you subclassing here. If it is a view, what is it nested in? Why do you expect the bounds to remain unchanged during rotation?

Comment: figured it out ... [self setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRedraw]; fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want you rect to be of same size in every orientation than do this!

```
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);

// the axis is a rect ...
//axis start point
CGFloat boxSize = MIN(viewBounds.size.width, viewBounds.size.height);
CGFloat axisStartX = boxSize * LEFT_EXCLUSION_LENGTH_PERCENT;
CGFloat axisStartY = boxSize * UNDER_EXCLUSION_LENGTH_PERCENT;

CGFloat axisLength = boxSize - (boxSize * OVER_EXCLUSION_LENGTH_PERCENT) - boxSize * UNDER_EXCLUSION_LENGTH_PERCENT;
CGContextAddRect(ctx, CGRectMake(axisStartX, axisStartY, AXIS_LINE_WIDTH, axisLength));


CGContextFillPath(ctx);
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

The idea here is that whatever the orientation is, the size remains same and visible on screen.

hope that helps!

Comment: It still changes size ... when the view goes to landscape the horizontal line becomes thinner ... and the vertical one (I use this for 2 lines ) bolder ...